# If I wanted to generate a sequence of elements using the element position in the sequence as a variable, how would that variable be written?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

I'm trying to create a sequence of elements which are dependent on their position in the sequence. What I mean is that I want the value $r$ in position 1 equal to 1, on position 2 equal to 2 and so on. E.g.

$$\langle r, r, r, r, r, r\rangle=\langle 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6\rangle$$
$$\langle 2^r, 2^r, 2^r, 2^r, 2^r, 2^r\rangle=\langle 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64\rangle$$

My first thought is having 2 sequences of elements. One of $r$ being all natural numbers and the second being the sequence I'm using $r$ in (The sequence called $\Bbb X$.) next to each other like so:

$$r=\langle 0, 1, 2, 3,\dots\rangle=\Bbb N$$
$$\Bbb X=\langle 2^{r+1}, 2^{r+1}, 2^{r+1}, 2^{r+1}, 2^{r+1}, 2^{r+1}\rangle$$

Both combining to make:

$$\langle 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64\rangle$$

Is there some sort of pre-existing symbol or notation to represent the value of whatever position an element is in a sequence, changing the value of an expression like $2^{r+1}$ based on its position?

Comment: A set is not ordered, you shouldn't use it when you *mean* list / sequence

Comment: Also, we usually consider $0$ to be a part of the natural numbers $\mathbb N$

Comment: @Vsotvep aren't the natural numbers all integers of a positive value, excluding 0 as it is neither negative nor positive (that's what I've learnt from other people and I'm not sure if it's true)?

Comment: Sometimes $0$ is included, sometimes it is excluded. In the area of set theory, including $0$ is standard, as it is the smallest ordinal (& cardinal) number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will use curly brackets $\{\}$ to denote *sets* and angle brackets $\langle\rangle$ to denote *sequences*.

A *set* is something fundamentally different from a *sequence*, since sets are not ordered. That is, the sets $\{1,1,1,2,4,3\}$ and $\{4,2,3,1\}$ are equal: multiplicity and order of elements does not matter. For sequences the order does matter, so $\langle 1,1,2\rangle$, $\langle 1,2\rangle$ and $\langle 2,1\rangle$ are all distinct from each other.

---

If you want to create a sequence $\langle a_1,a_2,\dots,a_i,\dots\rangle$ (finite or infinite) with each element having a value dependent on its position, I would write it as $\langle f(i)\mid i\in I\rangle$, where $I$ is an ordered list of indices, and $f$ is a function with the index as input.

For example:

- $\mathbb X=\langle 2^r\mid 1\leq r\leq 6\rangle=\langle2,4,8,16,32,64\rangle$
- $\langle n\mid n\in\mathbb Z_{>0}\rangle=\langle1,2,3,4,\dots\rangle$

In both of these examples it is left *implicit* that the indices $r$ and $n$ are ordered from small to large in the usual way.

---

For creating sets you could use the same notation, but here the order doesn't matter. So as a set we have $\{2^r\mid 1\leq r\leq 6\}=\{2,4,8,16,32,64\}=\{64,2,8, 16,32,4\}$.

Comment: And what if the equation changes for each element in the sequence? For example: $$\{2^r, r^r-1, sqrt(r)\}$$ and so on? Also what is the command for the angled brackets so that I can edit my post?

Comment: The angled brackets are denoted with `\langle` and `\rangle`

Comment: If you have a set, you could just take the union. If you want a sequence, I would define a function with cases. For example, a sequence that alternates between $2^n$ and $\sqrt n$ would be $\langle f(n)\mid n\in\mathbb N\rangle$ where $$f(n)=\begin{cases}
2^n&\text{if $n$ is even}\\
\sqrt{n}&\text{if $n$ is odd}
\end{cases}$$
This results in the sequence $\langle 1,1,4,\sqrt 3,16,\sqrt 5,64,\sqrt 7,\dots\rangle$

Comment: thank you. That's answered my question completely.